# count specific value over all dataframe in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe (235832 rows × 79 columns) that contains genotype data rows mean = variants columns mean = patients

I want to search many values in a dataframe ( all, not specific column or row )

So ,

I want to return the number of finding [-1, -1] or [0 -1] across all dataframe how can I do it in python

example of dataframe

```
0 1 2 3 ... 78

0 [-1, -1] [0, 0] [0, 0] ... [0 -1]

1 [0 0] [0,0] [-1 -1] ... [0 -1]

and so on until 235832
```

I want count [-1,-1] or [0,-1] in the dataframe
it return 4 in my example

Comment: What is `print (df.iloc[0,:2].tolist())` ?

Comment: why [-1,-1] counts 4 in your example? I see it only two time

Comment: please could you add a  sample output?

Answer (score 0):

Convert values to tuples by [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), compare by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and sum `True`s for count matched values:

```
a = np.array([0,-1])
b = np.array([-1,-1])
c = np.array([1,-1])

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[a,b,c],'b':[a,b,a],'c':[c,a,c]})
print (df)
          a         b        c
0   [0, -1]   [0, -1]  [1, -1]
1  [-1, -1]  [-1, -1]  [0, -1]
2   [1, -1]   [0, -1]  [1, -1]


out = df.applymap(tuple).isin([tuple( [0,-1] ), tuple( [-1,-1] )] ).sum().sum()
print (out)
6
```

Comment: Can I put two things I want to find in test?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think you just need to count the occurrences of [-1, -1] and [0, -1]. I am not sure about the formatting. But in general,

Suppose, your dataframe's name is `df`

```
df_melted = df.melt()
```

Running the cell above will get all the values of your original dataframe in ONE column, then, you can run

```
df['value'].value_counts()
```

This will return you the counts of all the values within including what you are seeking.

Comment: you mean in the second command df_melted['value'] ? I try this but it takes a long time and in the end the kernal is died !!! .. I don't know is there any solution? maybe kernal is died because the df_melted is large !

Comment: Can you tell me the data types you have in columns? I assume that they are string. Am I right?